# How to force Canvas event handlers to finish updating

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to use HTLM 5 Canvas KineticJS to build a box that contains a list.  I want to give the box a handle to drag it around with, and I would like to be able to drag the list items, too.  I have implemented this as a Kinetic.Group. The list items in my stripped-down example below are little Kinetic.Text objects.  I am having trouble getting attributes of the objects to update when I finish dragging them.  Running it in Chrome or Firefox, when I drag one of the  text object boxes and drop it, my dragend event handler removes it from the group, so it should disappear from the screen.  Instead, it stays visible until I mousedown on an element on the screen, then it disappears.

I have tried adding other event handlers, calling drawhit and drawscene functions, and using the simulate function to generate simulated mouse clicks.  These do have some effect, but I can't find any combination that leaves everything in the right state at the end of the dragend handler.  For example, in some cases the drag handle for the box doesn't work. In other versions of my code, similar odd effects occur, all seeming to require extra mouse clicks to cause the objects to finish updating.

I have looked in Canvas source for some function that will force a redraw, and searched on line, but have found nothing that seems intended for that purpose.  Ideally, Canvas would do this automatically, so I suspect that I am missing some obvious step.  Any ideas what it might be?

Here is my javascript:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 500,
    height: 200
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var group = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 50,
    y: 50
});

var box = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    points: [0, 20, 0, 100, 200, 100, 200, 0, 20, 0],
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: 2
});
group.add(box);     

var handle = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    points: [0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 0],
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: 2
});
group.add(handle);

handle.on('mouseover', function() {
    group.setDraggable(true);
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });

handle.on('mouseout', function() {
    group.setDraggable(false);
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
});     

var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'];
for(var n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    (function() {
        var i = n;
        var item = new Kinetic.Text({
            x: 20 + i * 25,
            y: 20,
            width: 20,
            height: 10,
            fill: colors[i],
            draggable: true,
            id: i,
        });

        group.add(item);

        item.on('dragend', function() {
            console.log('item dragend');
            id = this.getId();
            var children = group.getChildren();
            var len = children.length;
            for(var i = 2; i < len; i++) {
                if (id == children[i].getId()) {
                    children.splice(i,1);
                    break;
                };
            }
        });
    })();
};

layer.add(group);
stage.add(layer);
```

I use this HTML to run it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
      <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/v4.2.0/kinetic-v4.2.0.js"></script>    
    <script src="/Users/tsnichols/Documents/workspace/WebScheduler/listgroup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found the solution, I think.  I called stage.draw() at the end of the dragend event handler.

Comment: When you found the solution yourself, feel free to post a detailed answer. Answering your own question is not frowned upon on stackoverflow.com - it is even encouraged!

Comment: Just in case you are looking for performance optimization, you should user layer.draw() as it will only redraw the one layer instead of the entire stage. (this is only useful if you have multiple layers)

Answer (score 0):

Yup, stage.draw() is the simplest solution, but in case you have multiple layers and are using a bunch of animations, you should use layer.draw() to draw a single layer, for performance.